# Check if IP address is allowed through firewall

Tags: firewall, ip

Our cloud service requires that the client's server allow specific IP addresses be whitelisted in their firewall. If the IPs aren't whitelisted, the end users will experience issues, but the end users don't typically know if an IP address is whitelisted or not, so they then have to check with their network admin, which can take hours, if not days. I wanted to know if there is a way that I can check if a particular IP address is in fact whitelisted without them having to get with their network admin.

Comment: I suggest you add more information to your question. What kind of services does the server provide? Whitelisting a web server would make no sense, but whitelisting ssh for a web server would. You also need to break your question up into sentences, it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your application works for your clients, it works. If it doesn't, it doesn't. That's about all there is to it, unless they have some sort of L7-aware "fuzzy" matching going on that may permit some traffic to your app and deny other traffic, in which case the network team needs to be involved.

If your clients want to use your application, the onus is on them, *not you* to communicate requirements with their network team.

Comment: Thanks! the problem usually ends up being that a change is made to their network that end users aren't aware of, so when the customer submits a support ticket saying that our stuff isn't working, one of our steps is having them verify that they allow our specific IPs to communicate through their firewall, so if there was a way that we could just use Fiddler or something similar to see if that is an issue before reaching out to the customer, it would save some time.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing you can do from outside their firewall that would be of any use.